# What does this line have to do with anything? Python

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv
#line 2 and 5 correspound with the name "Filename"
txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r" % filename
print txt.read() #line 5 corresponds with this line... ".read" is a python function

print "Type the file name again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")
txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

How does `file_again = raw_input("> ")` correspound with the line bellow it, and what does `file_again` stand for?

Comment: `file_again` is a string, presumably intended to be the name of a file, the contents of which are then printed to the screen. Did you mean something specific by "correspond"?

Comment: This could have been solved by googling what the method `open` does

Answer (score 1):

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) will prompt the user to enter something. Before doing that, it will print out its argument. So in your case, `>` is printed first, then the user can enter a file name. Whatever the user entered is returned by `raw_input` and stored in the `file_again` variable. That is then used as an argument to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) which opens the  file with that name.

Answer (score 0):

`file_again = raw input("> ")`

In laymans terms `file_again` is now equal to `raw_input("> ")` or (the user input)

On the following line `txt_again` is now equal to or set to `open(file_again)` (which was just set to the user input)